# How to change admin route prefix for typus on rails3.1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, typus

I want to change admin route path for typus on rails3.1.

[Before]
localhost:3000/admin

[After]
localhost:3000/example

3-1-unstable version implemented?

https://github.com/typus/typus/issues/120#issuecomment-651711

How to coding? route.rb? mountable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The typus project reports that this is "not supported" in the github issue queue